# Git Deployment - Changes don't deploy

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket

I'm new to git and got some trouble to make it run.

That's my setup:

- local development with XAMPP
- Git with dev, stage and production branch
- stage Server
- I use Sourcetree, Bitbucket, FTPloy (automatic deployment)

So that's what I did so far:

1. Created a testfile index.html in my local environment
2. Commit and pushed it to dev branch -> gets to bitbucket without a hassle.
3. Setup FTPloy to my stage branch.
4. Merged div into stage branch.
5. index.html got uploaded to my stage server.

But if I add a file or change index.html on my local environment and merge the dev branch into stage branch it gets updated in bitbucket.
But the deploy just doesn't happen.

Why did it work on the first initial commit and not now?
Am I doing something totally wrong? Thought that would be the correct workflow?

Comment: Did you commit and push the second change after adding the file in the local environment to the dev environment and then merge to stage branch?

Comment: @VamsiRavi
Yeah I add the file to the local environment -> then commit and push it to dev branch -> then i merge the dev branch into the stage branch

Comment: ok I think this was an error from FTPloy oO It deployed the changes like 6 hours later oO
but is my "workflow" correct so far?